# Setting the height & width of a div's background image, without knowing them in advance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asynchronous

*using jQuery:*

Whenever someone adds a background image to a div, the width and height of the background image need to be known in advance.

e.g.

```
$("#id-of-some-div").css(
{
   backgroundImage: 'url(' + backgroundImageUrl + ')',
   height: 200,
   width: 450,
   position: 'absolute',
   top: 20,
   left: 20
});
```

Could I get the size of the image simply by using code as follows :

*I've tested the following but it's not working, is it because I cannot use a return statement inside a $.load function? -I'm guessing a return statement needs to always be synchronous right?*

e.g.

```
var bgImageUrl = "/*insert image url*/";

var backgroundImageHeightAndWidth = function(backgroundImageUrl)
{
   var backgroundImageSize = [];
   var backgroundImage = new Image();
   backgroundImage.src = backgroundImageUrl;
   backgroundImage.id = "background-image-id";
   $("#background-image-id").load(function ()
   {
      backgroundImageSize.push($("#background-image-id").height());
      backgroundImageSize.push($("#background-image-id").width());
      return backgroundImageSize;   
   });
};
var backgroundImageHeightAndWidthArray = backgroundImageHeightAndWidth();
var backgroundImageHeight = backgroundImageHeightAndWidthArray[0];
var backgroundImageWidth = backgroundImageHeightAndWidthArray[1];

$("#id-of-some-div").css(
{
   backgroundImage: 'url(' + backgroundImageUrl + ')',
   height: backgroundImageHeight,
   width: backgroundImageWidth,
   position: 'absolute',
   top: 20,
   left: 20
});
```

Comment: It's overly complicated, but yes, waiting for the onload event will work, but set the source after the onload handler, and it is async, so you can't use the returned data until the onload event has happened, and that's the major problem with your code.

Comment: The image starts loading as soon as I set its source, so I cannot set it's source inside or after the $.load function. It doesn't make sense, or am I missing something? I'm also returning data inside the $.load function, which means that I am returning it as soon as the image has finished loading. But the $.load function is obviously a polling function and I don't think I can use return statements inside polling functions, that's the problem I believe.

Comment: It's async, so you can't return a value from that function like that, you should set the styles inside the onload function. I've added an answer to show how it's done, and it's even whithout jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var bg = "/*insert image url*/";

var bgimg = new Image();
bgimg.onload = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('id_of_element');
    elem.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg + ')';
    elem.style.height          = this.height + 'px';
    elem.style.width           = this.width + 'px';
    elem.style.position        = 'absolute',
    elem.style.top             = '20px';
    elem.style.left            = '20px';
});
bgimg.src = bg;
```

Comment: I see, I got it! That's perfect! Thanks! :)